# In Sharepoint context EF, how to find the data and the field of the record that causes Invalid cast exception

Tags: entity-framework, sharepoint

I have some thing similar to following in

```
var contractList = (from c in db.Customers select c).ToList();
```

Which results in below error:

> "Invalid cast Exception"

How does SharePoint fill the entity sets? I have been going trough the entire solution to find where the raw data gets converted to the entity but can not find it in our code. I am assuming it is handled behind the scene by SharePoint, but how do I find the cause the of the cast exception? That is all I get out of stack trace, I have tried building with debug set to true, but no extra info is coming about what is causing cast issue, or even when found the field how to handle it.

By trial and error have found the offending records id, and when it is excluded all works fine.

But I am at a loss on what is the actual data for the offending record! How do I get the raw data table returned before it being type cast ( Under the SharePoint context )?

I can not tell which field is causing the cast exception. Every detail is managed by SharePoint, after finding the problematic field I am planning to change the entity definition for Customer.

PS : I have asked this question in the [SharePoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/178464) but I think this more appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Share point and SP metal lies to you, even looking in VS field list the field was suppose to be int? .

Changed the type of fields (every possible fields that might caused the exception one by one to object ) was discovered that the field that was suppose to be int? , was actually passing a string value of a number e.g. "4" by sharepoint, having had dumped raw data from Sharepoint this was still not visible, a cell having value int 4 and another having string 4 are indistinguishable in excel.

Short answer turn your fields types on the entity to object and then inspect them after they are hydrated from SharePoint.